# Copy Command with "%" in path name

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I am trying to write a bat file to copy some files into a new directory (which exists).

Here is my command:

```
copy ".\050-9800-JJJ-DSC-BAW-MEE-00019-01*.pdf" "T:\201201.00 TCO - Tengiz, Kazakhstan\12.0-Submittals\100% IFC\DocsForVoid"
```

Notice that the destination path has a directory name that contains "%".  When I see the output in powershell I get the error that the system cannot find the path specified.  The path echoed in the command does not contain the "%" character . . . please note that I did not name this directory, and it may be problematic to rename it.  Is there any way to get this to work?

Here is powershell output (sample):

```
T:\201201.00 TCO - Tengiz, Kazakhstan\08.6-Document Control\CW985786 Documents to be Uploaded to POL\015-C041-ITM-TRN-BA
W-FGP-00159>copy ".\050-9800-JJJ-DSC-BAW-MEE-00019-01*.pdf" "T:\201201.00 TCO - Tengiz, Kazakhstan\12.0-Submittals\100 I
FC\DocsForVoid"
.\050-9800-JJJ-DSC-BAW-MEE-00019-01_H04.pdf
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: What version of powershell? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Not sure . . . is there a way to get powershell to tell me what version it is?

Comment: $host.Version at the command line

Comment: That error message looks more like cmd.exe than PowerShell.

Comment: @EBGreen 2.0.-1.-1 (Major, Minor, Build, Revision) . . . I've not seen -1 before like that.

Comment: @dangph I can assure you that it is indeed powershell

Comment: I've never see a PS version like that before either. I would just go ahead and upgrade if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting two `&&` instead of one.  This is will [escape](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) the special character.